# jquery rounded images slider

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a jquery slider of rounded images. Here is HTML

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


   var $lis = $('ul').find('li'),
     length = $lis.length;

   $lis.each(function(index, item) {
     $(item).attr('data-id', index);
   });


   function slider($lis, index, length) {
     $lis.each(function(index, item) {
       item.className = '';
     });
     index += length;
     $($lis[index % length]).addClass('active');
     $($lis[(index - 1) % length]).addClass('left1');
     $($lis[(index - 2) % length]).addClass('left2');
     $($lis[(index + 1) % length]).addClass('right1');
     $($lis[(index + 2) % length]).addClass('right2');
   }


   slider($lis, 2, length);

   $lis.on('click', function(e) {
     var id = parseInt($(e.target).parents('li').attr('data-id'));
     slider($lis, id, length);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="peopleSlider" class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="scrollLeft" id="leftArrow">Left</a><a href="#" class="scrollRight" id="rightArrow">Right</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="left2">
        <img src="img/1.png" width="150" height="150">
      </li>

      <li class="left1">
        <img src="img/2.png" width="150" height="150">
      </li>

      <li class="active">
        <img src="img/3.png" width="150" height="150">
      </li>

      <li class="right1">
        <img src="img/4.png" width="150" height="150">
      </li>

      <li class="right2">
        <img src="img/5.png" width="150" height="150">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

My problem is to make it move after click on "Left" and "Right" buttons. I have a few ideas in my head, but don't know how to implement them. I guess i need to get index parameter of .active image and change it to -1 for "left" and +1 for "right", but i have no clue how to do this. May be can some one give me a hint, or show something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

So conceptually, what you want to do is animate the "left" css position of your  element. So the first thing you will need is to know the width of each "slide":

```
var slide_width = $lis.first().outerWidth(true);
```

Then, when you want to slide to the 3rd slide, for instance, assuming that means placing the 3rd slide to the far left of your slider, you'll do so just by animating the left property of your ul element:

```
$('ul').animate({left: (0 - ((slide_index) * slide_width)) + "px"});
```

To be nice, you'll likely also want to make sure if you ask to slide to the very last slide, for instance, it doesn't slide it all the way to the left and then have nothing else to show on the right of it. You want to make sure the left *absolute* value you calculate is always less than your slider's full innerWidth.

You'll need to make sure the container around your  is set to `overflow: hidden;` in css, of course, wihta `position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;` and that should do it!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did it. It was so simple. Here is the code:

```
$('#leftArrow').click(function(e){
  var id = parseInt($('.left1').attr('data-id'));
  slider($lis,id,length);
});
$('#rightArrow').click(function(e){
  var id = parseInt($('.right1').attr('data-id'));
  slider($lis,id,length);
});
```